# Query to call values matching a column in a local dataframe with mysql

Tags: python, mysql

so I am using PyMySQL to access an SQL database where I want to extract data from a dataframe matching the id's of a column I have in a local dataframe

local_df

```
id
1
3
11
.
```

sql_df

```
id   feat
1    f
2    g
3    d
4    g
5    q
6    p
.    .
```

is it possible to create a query that extracts only the rows with matching id's?

something like

```
query = """
SELECT * 
FROM sql_df
WHERE id(local_df) = id(sql_df)
"""
```

sorry for the messy representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an [INNER JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT sql_df.* 
FROM sql_df
INNER JOIN local_df on sql_df.id =local_df.id
```

You have other ways using `EXIST` or `IN`  like:

```
SELECT sql_df.* 
FROM sql_df
WHERE EXISTS (select null from local_df where sql_df.id=local_df.id)
```

Using `IN`

```
SELECT sql_df.* 
FROM sql_df
WHERE id in (select distinct id from local_df)
```

Comment: Hi Ergest, thank you for commenting, I have tried the solutions you proposed by I get a 'Error: '(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax...'; the local dataframe is in the same folder of the python script so I did not specify any kind of path, should I change any notation?

Comment: @andriy can you post the full code in which you are getting the error ?

Comment: I found the issue, however now I get this new error: Error: '(1146, "Table 'sql_database.local_df' doesn't exist")'

Comment: @andriy I can't know the tables on your database. Check the table names

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, the error I get is that the table from which I am getting the id's it's not in the online sql database I am accessing, and indeed it is not, its on my computer, that's what I meant by local. Anyway, thank you for your help, I am new to mysql and I will certainly use the commands you have posted